# AJAX: Statusbar: force update of UpdatePanel while function executes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have a label inside an update panel which I would like to use as a status bar.

Basically the user clicks a button which executes a main function that performs a series of tasks. I'd like to inform the user as to the state of the function as it progresses e.g.:

Stage 1: Retrieving data...

Stage 2: Calculating values...

Stage 3: Printing values...

Stage 4: Done!

I've tried updating the updatepanel directly from the function but it only updates the panel at the end of function (stage 4) and shows "Done!" (which I understand is how it should work).

I've been looking into timers and threads to try and update the panel separate to the main function but I thought I'd post here in case anyone has any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you put an Update Panel around the label as well?  Set UpdateMode to conditional, then when executing your stages, set the label's text then updatePanelProgress.Update() should do it

Comment: Yeah i've tried that, it seems to only update after the last stage... i believe the updatePanel is only meant to update after the calling function is finished? So I'm trying to find a way around this